# autorunning supervisorctl laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

short summary of our problem:

in our server i have service supervisor that have function to autorun email notifications from laravel

```
supervisorctl start laravel-worker:* 
//this is the syntax i was using
```

but its already 2 month this syntax can't be running automatically i must force run manual

i have tried it at local the syntax was fine and i already make sure the local setting and online setting have same exact setting

can u guys help me to discover what's wrong with the server ???

if you need more info just said so i will tried my best to provide you guys the info

[image]

Comment: Do you have something useful in your logs?

Comment: Sometimes some workers are like hanging (running but stop getting queue messages) and supervisorctl does not automatically restart them, so I have to monitor and manually restart them.
Is there something wrong with the configuration? What can I do to prevent this to happen in the future?
Thank you.